# How to call multiple invoke operations one by one?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have some invoke operations (all different) that I need to call based on the user selected items that are stored in an `ObservableCollection` and return a string/int value.

Now when the selection is only one item it is straight forward, I can call and use the `Completed` event and get my return value.

I have approx <= 8 items in the list I need to iterate and perform the `invoke` operation on each.

I see the `foreach` will not really wait for the `InvokeOperation` to finish  and just continuously iterates till the end of the list making them run in parallel..sort of...

How do I perform only one operation at once and iterate only when the previous operation is completed (irrespective of the result)?

1 by 1 execution of InvokeOperations is what I'm looking for..any clues, hints..?

Let me know if I'm unclear..

Cheers.

EDIT: The `InvokeOperation`(s) are different from each other. Each of them doin different operations on the DB which can be time consuming.The main reason for looking into executing them 1-1 is to update the user screen with the output (success/fail) for each of them and not do all at once.

```
//Pseudo-code
foreach (var item in SelectedItems) 
{

    var id = item.ID;

    switch(id) 
    {    
      case: 1
         InvokeOperataion<int> inv = context.PerformUpdateFor_1(item);
         inv.Completed += (s,a) => { 
         //get the value assign it to Textblock.
         };
         break;
      case: 2
         InvokeOperataion<int> inv = context.PerformUpdateFor_2(item);
         inv.Completed += (s,a) => { 
         //get the value assign it to Textblock.
         };
         break;
//Other cases similar to this    
   }

}
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "invoke operations"? Please give us some code.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to call a (asynchronous) method for each selected items, that he has got a method signature that only takes one item at a time and don't know how to chain the calls.
My first suggestion would be to write a method that takes a collection of items, call it asynchronously and do the foreach inside this method.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Reactive Extensions for Silverlight. You will easily be able to wrap your RIA Services `InvokeOperation` in an `IObservable` which represents its asynchronous completion. One way to do this involves the `Observable.Create` method.

After that, you will be able to compose the collection of `IObservables` in many ways: executing them in sequence using `Observable.Concat`, executing them in parallel using `Observable.ForkJoin`, filtering them, joining them etc.

I have used this successfully for RIA Services' load operations, and to a smaller extent invoke operations. The composability of observables in my opinion is much nicer to work with than writing callback methods explicitly.

Here is a blog post outlining the approach for load operations, but the approach will be very similar: [Linq Query Expression Syntax with RIA Domain Context](http://www.tonyabell.com/blog/2011/7/14/linq-query-expression-syntax-with-ria-domain-context.html)